# How to pass nested Rails ActiveRecord query result to gon?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm using the gon gem in my Rails 4 app to pass values from my controller to JavaScript. I've used gon in other parts of my app, it works fine, so it's not related to whether the gem is loaded properly.

I have the following models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses
  end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
end
```

I assign the query result like this:

```
gon.my_js_var = @my_instance_var = Address.includes(:person, :city).where("person_id = 1")
```

`@my_instance_var` has all the values I need, e.g. `@my_instance_var[i].city.name` shows the correct value. But, `gon.my_js_var` only has the columns from Address model, nothing from Person or City, e.g. `gon.my_js_var[i].city is undefined`.

Am I missing something here? Or should I be doing this a different way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up re-writing the query with a raw inner join SQL, then call `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` on it, so the result set contains all records, no nested lookup.

Comment: Hi @jiax, I'm trying to figure this out too, can you post the exact code you wrote and in what files? I'd love a bit more direction since I've never written raw SQL and am not sure where the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` goes

Comment: @james, you can construct your SQL query in your model like: `stmt = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"`, then `result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(stmt)`, then pass `result` back to you `gon` object

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`to_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) as `JSON` is accessible by `gon`:

```
@my_instance_var = Address.includes(:person, :city).where("person_id = 1")
gon.my_js_var = @my_instance_var.to_json(include: [ :person, :city ])
```

Comment: `to_json` returns a string representation, any way to return the full query result in an object?

Answer (score 0):

Use `as_json`

```
gon.my_js_var = Address.where("person_id = 1").as_json.(include: [:person,:city])
```